# Javascript saving form searches

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I **save data (searches) in session/localmachine**, I mean, save anywhere less DB, all form fields for future use everytime that form is submited?

(...)

```
$('#button_submit').click(function() {
    var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
    var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    var tempArr = new Array();
    var json = window.sessionStorage['search'];
    if(json)
        tempArr = JSON.parse(json);
    tempArr.push(JSON.parse('{"start_date" : "'+start_date+'" , "end_date" : "'+end_date+'" , "type" : "'+type+'"}'));
    window.sessionStorage['search'] = JSON.stringify(tempArr);
    drawChart(start_date, end_date, type)
});
```

(...)

This code dont solve my problem.

I need to save `start_date`, `end_date` and `type` values everytime form is submited and create some buttons/links for that old searches to be able to see old results.

The point is *grab* those values and *stick* them in this **drawChart(start_date, end_date, type)**. This is the function that will produce my results.

with my code i got this `[{"start_date":"2012-02-05","end_date":"2012-12-26","type":"pie"}]` this is tempArray[0]. But what I need is grab this `start_date`, `end_date` and `type` separated values , not like it is atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, the use of suitable object localSorage, though it is not supported by all browsers. Supported browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Example

```
localStorage.setItem('resultSearch', JSON.stringify({a: "1234"}));
.....
// submit, and reload page
var b = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resultSearch'));
```

Comment: with my code i got this `[{"start_date":"2012-02-05","end_date":"2012-12-26","type":"pie"}]` this is tempArray[0]. But what I need is grab this `start_date`, `end_date` and `type` separated values , not like it is atm

Answer (score 0):

you could use [persistjs](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557). if you want to write it by yourself, just use the localStorage (not the SessionStorage) with cookies as fallback (basically for <= IE7) to save old searches. a good explanation can be found here (including the fallback code):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage